# Extract data from row names and insert into table

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like

```
                ML1    ML1 SD       ML2    ML2 SD ...
aPhysics0 0.8730469 0.3329205 0.5950521 0.4908820
aPhysics1 0.8471074 0.3598839 0.6473829 0.4777848
aPhysics2 0.8593750 0.3476343 0.7031250 0.4568810
aPhysics3 0.8875000 0.3159806 0.7000000 0.4582576
aPhysics4 0.7962963 0.4027512 0.7654321 0.4237285
...
```

And I want to use the row names to create a data frame that looks like

```
     Institution Subject Class       ML1    ML1 SD       ML2    ML2 SD ...
[1,]           A Physics     0 0.8730469 0.3329205 0.5950521 0.4908820
[2,]           A Physics     1 0.8471074 0.3598839 0.6473829 0.4777848
[3,]           A Physics     2 0.8593750 0.3476343 0.7031250 0.4568810
[4,]           A Physics     3 0.8875000 0.3159806 0.7000000 0.4582576
[5,]           A Physics     4 0.7962963 0.4027512 0.7654321 0.4237285
...
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data.frame is df,

```
header <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("Physics", " Physics ", 
                rownames(df)), " ")))
names(header) <- c("Institution", "Subject", "Class")
cbind(header, df)
df.out <- cbind(header, df)
df.out$Institution <- toupper(df.out$Institution)
```

If you've more subjects (generalised solution):

```
header <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("^([a-z])(.*)([0-9])$", 
                 "\\1 \\2 \\3", rownames(df)), " ")))
names(header) <- c("Institution", "Subject", "Class")
df.out <- cbind(header, df)
df.out$Institution <- toupper(df.out$Institution)
```

Comment: One note: the generalized solution is assuming only one digit for the class number.  To make it more flexible, you'll want to make your middle regex pattern lazy, and make the last regex pattern greedy.  Something like so: `^(\\w)(\\w+?)(\\d+)$`  If you also want to allow for multiple institution letters, you'll need to filter based on the capital letter with something like: `^(\\w+)([A-Z][a-z]+?)(\\d+)$`

Comment: @Dinre, assuming that the subject always begins with a capital letter, you can change `^[a-z]` to `^[a-z]{0,n}` where n is the maximum length you expect. And similarly at the end `[0-9]+$`. This should be sufficient.

Comment: That is the same thing, only written in opposite order.  My comment wasn't a criticism; I was pointing out for the OP (and others who may visit this question later) how to extend this application to be more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the row names are of the form (1 lowercase char-character string-1 digit number), you can use some regex with `gsub`:

```
#test data
x <- data.frame(ML1=runif(5),ML2=runif(5),row.names=paste0("aPhysics",1:5))

#logic
transform(x, Institution=toupper(gsub("^([a-z])([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9])$","\\1",rownames(x))), Subject=gsub("^([a-z])([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9])$","\\2",rownames(x)), Class=gsub("^([a-z])([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9])$","\\3",rownames(x)))
                 ML1       ML2 Institution Subject Class
aPhysics1 0.51680701 0.4102757           A Physics     1
aPhysics2 0.60388358 0.7438400           A Physics     2
aPhysics3 0.26504243 0.7598557           A Physics     3
aPhysics4 0.55900273 0.5263205           A Physics     4
aPhysics5 0.05589591 0.7903568           A Physics     5
```